# JSTL on remote Tomcat server breaks webapp

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, jstl

As a school assignment I am making a webapp. It works as expected when I run it on a local server (database server is still remote though), however when deployed to a remote Tomcat server where the assignments need to be for submission, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:278)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:76)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:124)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:411)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1430)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
controller.GameServlet.listAllGames(GameServlet.java:39)
controller.GameServlet.doGet(GameServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

If I refresh the page a few times sometimes a different error is displayed too:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.games_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
controller.GameServlet.listAllGames(GameServlet.java:39)
controller.GameServlet.doGet(GameServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have been looking up these errors for hours now and tried multiple suggestions from Stackoverflow and other sources.
The application uses Maven. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>game</groupId>
<artifactId>game</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>game Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>game</finalName>
</build>
```

The jstl-1.2.jar file is located in the webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder as are all the other .jar files.
Here is the beginning for each of my .jsp files:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

I have been stuck with this for hours now and everything I have tried so far has had no results, I feel like I am missing something obvious though.

Comment: You bundled both JSTL 1.1 and 1.2. Why? Get rid of JSTL 1.1 (that `taglibs:standard`). Although I'd have expected different problem symptom than the one presented in your question.

Comment: It is a remnant of when I was looking up fixes for my problem. The problem occured before adding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a serverside problem as other students have reported this problem. Thus solving it is out of my hands. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the remote servers jsp version is outdated. Since jsp-2.0 taglibs are detected automatically. I see two options. Either include the taglib-tag in your web.xml (see also http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/RemovingTaglibFromWeb.xml) or incorporate the latest jsp-api in your pom.xml.

Comment: What I wrote is probably applicable for custom tags only but I would make the jsp and jstl-versions go along together.

Comment: Stack trace hints Tomcat 8.0. This is definitely not "outdated".

Answer (score -1):

Apparently either auto detection of the remote server is not working or the jar is not in place.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently auto detect of remote server is not working or the jar is not in place for whatever reasons.